# Can you use a named JSON property to pass a complex object to a C# controller?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, api

I'm having trouble with some JSON data populating a C# object in the parameter of a POST method on my Web API controller when I try to assign a property name in my JSON object.

Here is my API controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage MyResource(MyComplexClass myClass)
{
    var test = myClass.Name;

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

Here is the `MyComplexClass`:

```
public class MyComplexClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my `AJAX` call:

```
<script>
    function test() {
        var innerData = {
            Name: 'Bob Loblaw',
            Id: "1"
        };

        var myData = {
            myClass: innerData
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "api/Test/MyResource",
            data: JSON.stringify(myData),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                // do success stuff
            },
            error: function (err) {
                // do error stuff
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The problem is: when I include the `innerData` object as a property in the `myData` object in my JS code, the properties of the `myClass` object are all `null`.

I know that if I pass the `innerData` into the `AJAX` call itself, the `myClass` object is populated properly, but I'm curious about why I can't use a named JSON property to pass a complex C# object to the controller.

Does anyone know how to pass the `myClass` object as a named JSON property, or can you give an explanation as to why I can't?

**Rephrased question:**

If this JSON object:

```
var data = {
    Name: 'Bob Loblaw',
    Id: "1"
};
```

matches up with this controller method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage MyResource(string Name, string Id)
```

Why doesn't this JSON object:

```
var data = {
    myClass: { Name: 'Bob Loblaw', Id: "1" }
};
```

match up with this controller method?

```
public HttpResponseMessage MyResource(MyComplexClass myClass)
```

**Additional question:**

Is it possible to have an API method declared as the following:

```
public HttpResponseMessage MyResource(MyComplexClass myClass, string anotherValue)
```

And if so, how would the JSON object be structured?

Comment: try `var myData = innerData;` and send that

Comment: `MyComplexClass` is expecting an object with two keys; Name and Id.  But you are not giving it that.  So it doesn't have anything to map to. `MyComplexClass` does not have a field of `myClass` that would properly map your input to it

Comment: Is it Web API 2?

Comment: No I am using MVC version 5.2.3 with a similar version of Web API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why doesn't this JSON object:

```
var data = {
    myClass: { Name: 'Bob Loblaw', Id: "1" }
};
```

match up with this controller method?

```
public HttpResponseMessage MyResource(MyComplexClass myClass)
```

Because of how model binding works in WEB API, when you send

```
var data = {
    Name: 'Bob Loblaw',
    Id: "1"
};
```

WEB API binds the properties of the json object you sent to the properties of the class you defined as a parameter.

So, in order to match

```
var data = {
    myClass: { Name: 'Bob Loblaw', Id: "1" }
};
```

MyComplexClass would need to be defined as

```
public class MyComplexClass
{
    public Object myClass{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So to go one step further: could I see a Web API method declaration like this: `public HttpResponseMessage MyResource(MyComplexClass myClass, string anotherValue)` and if so, how would that JSON object be structured? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What people tend to do is, instead of having multiple parameters (MyComplexClass myClass, string anotherValue) they define a model (class) that combines all of the properties you need. So if MyComplexClass has 2 properties, you create a new class just for the resource with those 2 properties and a string.
In MVC they are called view models, check them out

Comment: But, it if you insist the json would be var data = { Name: 'Bob Loblaw', Id: "1" , anotherValue : "Johnny"} would work

Comment: Okay thanks! I kinda figured that the multiple parameter thing was a poor standard. The reason I am asking is that I am writing an self documenting API tool that will allow a user to try out a method (basically automating a Postman form) and am trying to anticipate any poor API designs that could cause trouble.

Comment: Using `var data = { Name: 'Bob Loblaw', Id: "1" , anotherValue : "Johnny"}` on the `(MyComplexClass myClass, string anotherValue)` method returns a `404 Not Found` error. I wonder if that's even a possible way of declaring a POST method...

Comment: Hum... Let me see that ajax

Comment: So I passed this JSON object into the AJAX call outlined in my `scripts` section of my question: `var myData = { Name: 'Bob Loblaw', Id: "1", anotherValue: "hello world" };`

Comment: Did you change the definition of the class MyComplexClass from your question?  Is it still defined like this ?:
public class MyComplexClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

Comment: Yep you got it, the class is still defined as it is in the question and what you posted.

Comment: Is your controller extending from apiController or from Controller. If it's extending from apiController, are you using Web Api or Web Api 2?

Comment: I'm extending from the `ApiController` and Web API 2

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api.
ApiControllers behave different from controllers used in MVC, for simplicity they don't work directly with multiple objects as parameters, you'll have to create a model binder if you want to use more than one object, or create an unified model with all the properties you need

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've nested the innerData object and C# doesn't know what it is. You could either not nest that object by just passing the innerData to ajax or have another layer to your C# object like so:

```
public class MyOuterClass
{
    public MyComplexClass innerData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What I don't understand is that this method declaration: `public HttpResponseMessage MyResource(MyComplexClass myClass)` and this one: `public HttpResponseMessage MyResource(string Name, string Id)` are treated the same way when dealing with JSON objects. Is there something in the MVC framework that determines this?

Comment: I added some extra phrasing to the bottom of my question post that might clarify what I'm asking

Comment: I think the missing piece here might be the serialization of the json object?